# TFS error: Merge must finish before the Pull Request can be completed

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

We have a PR in TFS which cannot be completed or abandoned, because the button is grayed out/disabled. The tooltip on hover says:

> Merge must finish before the Pull Request can be completed
>
> Merge in progress ... [Abandon] [Restart Merge]

Screenshot (notice the grayed out button):

[image]

How do we complete it? Is there an unfinished merge in git? If so, how was the branch pushed in the first place? And why can't it be Abandoned at least?

Googling with the full error text doesn't yield any results, it hasn't been documented anywhere on the internet it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a merge that's blocked or stuck, you could try to click the **triple-dot menu** (...) next to the "Complete" button and choose the "**Restart merge**" option to start a new merge job.

The root cause was an issue with the job agents that perform merges running out of disk space.

If above is not work, also try to open two browsers and delete the source branch, then **abandon** your PR, then **Undo the branch deletion**. You could finally either reactivate the PR again or create a new one.

[image]

We have a open live site investigation regarding this issue. Please refer to the following for more information:

[**Issues with Pull Requests on Visual Studio Team Services - 03/17 -Mitigated**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=13636)

Comment: Seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: For my situation it's anyone else but me who opens a pull request that tries to complete receives the "Merge in progress" error message.
But if I abandon the pull request and then reactivate it and then try to complete the pull request myself, it completes just fine.

Comment: I get this in my event viewer.
`
Detailed Message: The subscriber Pull Request Unattended Completion Failed Subscriber raised an exception while being notified of event Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.UnattendedCompletionFailedNotification.

Exception Message: TF401180: The requested pull request was not found. (type GitPullRequestNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.TeamFoundationGitPullRequestService.GetPullRequestDetails(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ITfsGitRepository repository, 

...
`
Truncated because of character limit

Comment: the only option to fix it for me was reboot of the server

Answer (score 3):

"Abandon" then "reactivate" the PR works for me.

[image]

First, What you need to do is open dropdown next to the "complete" button, then select "abandon".
The wording on "complete" button will changed to "reactivate".

Then just click the "reactivate" button.

In my case the status is directly goes to completed.

Hope my explanation can help.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if this is a right issue: you might have the right to review but not approve. (See [Review code with pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests))

Second, check the branch policy:

> The number of required approvals in a pull request is set from the [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies) for the branch. Pull requests can be completed if the number of required approvals is met, even if other reviewers have rejected the changes.

Third, I suppose that in order to abandon the PR, you might need to abandon first the merge in progress.