# Can't complete pull request on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, pull-request

I'm not sure since when,our team can't complete pull request on Azure DevOps (without any file conflict)

[image]

Message on picture means "merge must finish before the pull request can be completed"

Few weeks ago we can still complete pull request directly,and we use visual studio 2019 as git client

Comment: after updating petch , the problem has been solved.

Comment: Glad to know the problem has been solved! This seems happen before my answer :D. Would you please post an answer about how the problem got sovled and [mark it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TFS error: Merge must finish before the Pull Request can be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728924/tfs-error-merge-must-finish-before-the-pull-request-can-be-completed)

Answer (score 1):

This situation seems just like this one [TFS error: Merge must finish before the Pull Request can be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728924/tfs-error-merge-must-finish-before-the-pull-request-can-be-completed)
.

As mentioned in above thread, the reason for this issue is the job agents that perform merges running out of disk space.

To solve this problem, you can restart the murge by click the triple-dot menu and click `Restart merge`

If this does not work, *open two browsers and delete the source branch, then abandon your PR, then Undo the branch deletion. You could finally either reactivate the PR again or create a new one.*