# Missing Azure Devops Complete Pull Request button when there are conflicts

Tags: git, azure-devops, merge-conflict-resolution

My pull request has conflicts but I can not find anywhere to resolve them in either DevOps or VS2019

There is More Actions Tool Tip

[image: More actions tool tip]

Here are the actions

[image: Complete is disabled]

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-the-pull-request) indicate that VS2019 has some Pull Request features but I cannot see them in Team Explorer or under the Git menu

In VS2019 in the Git Changes tab, working in the fork that the pull request is for, when I pull I get a message that the repository is already up to date.

The Pull Request is from Master of the repository to Master of a fork.

Comment: Your pull can tell you that you are up to date doesn't mean that you are 'synced' with the target branch. So check that you have rebased or merged (depending on your strategy) your branch with the target branch. This action must raise conflicts that you will have to solve. And after don't forget to push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, there is no built-in feature can resolve the merge conflicts.

But we can use the Extension to achieve this feature in Azure DevOps: [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)

[image]

Comment: Oh dear, I don't really want to install an experiment.

Comment: understand. But in this case, this extension may make this issue easier to alleviate.  Just a suggestion/option

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I got brave and tried it successfully!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to resolve merge conflicts directly within Azure DevOps. But you can resolve them with e. g. Visual Studio or using a command line.

This is the documentation you are looking for: [Resolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#resolve-merge-conflicts-1)

Comment: I updated the question to show that VS has no knowledge of the pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Move the mouse cursor over the grayed Complete button to see in a popup the reason why the merge cannot be completed.

For instance, in "[TFS error: Merge must finish before the Pull Request can be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46728924/6309)", the merge was not finished.
You can [abandon it, then reactivate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382889/6309).

Comment: Abandoning and Reactivating leaves me in the same situation

Comment: @Kirsten And what the tooltip above "Complete" says in your case?

Comment: @Kirsten I understand the arrow tooltip says "More Action". Does that mean there is no tooltip on the "complete" button itself?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the project to show the tool tip simply says "More Actions"

Comment: The complete button itself has no tooltip.