# Can't complete a Pull request on Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops

As an adminstrator of the repository, I can't see the option to complete an already approved pull request on Azure DevOps while my team member can see that option when they go into my pull request.

Does this have to do with policy or branch security, if so which option should be enabled?

[image]

Comment: Now I've never used Azure Devops but I use Bitbucket in an enterprise environment and I think they have the same base functionality. If you created the Pull Request you shouldn't be able to do it unless you assign yourself as Reviewer (which makes sense). So did you do that?

Comment: If you assign yourself as a reviewer, that control if you can approve your own pull request (not ideal) but once the Pull Request is approved, the next step is to "Complete" that Pull request which will merge that pull request branch into the default branch... which I can't seem to do right now.  In fact, I tested this out and assign myself as one of the reviewer on my own Pull Request, I still can't see the Complete option.

Comment: Hmm interesting, and you say your colleagues can? Have you tried clearing browser cache and cookies or log out then log back in?

Comment: No luck :(, i doubt it is though but I tried your suggestion none the less, I even tried it on a different browser and same result.

Comment: What branch policies do you have enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck at "A merge operation in progress"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304423/stuck-at-a-merge-operation-in-progress)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TL;DR

> It is my understanding from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops) that the **Contribute** permission is the one that should allow one to complete a pull request.

You may be seeing this because of a conflict in the permissions hierarchy.

We were having this exact issue with users in one of the organizations for our Azure Tenant. We ended up calling Azure support to get it resolved. Our issue was caused by some missing subscription and identity information after changing our corporate Azure tenant after an acquisition.

Make sure that you are not part of any groups that have the complete privilege **Denied**. Unless you're a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group on your organization, membership in a group that explicitly **Denies** any permission will deny your permission, even if you are in another group that explicitly **Allows** you the permission and even if you as an individual user are granted **Allow** on that permission.

It took me a few passes through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops#permission-settings) to understand that bit.

You might already know this, but if your permissions are inherited, you can click on the `Why?` link to view the breakdown of where your allow or deny status came from.

Below is an example w/ lots of screenshots to show this in action. It is my understanding from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops) that the **Contribute** permission is the one that should allow one to complete a pull request.

If, you're still having this issue after using a fine-tooth comb on your repository permissions and see nowhere that you are denied this permission based on your membership in any groups, then you may need to get in touch with Microsoft Support.

### The Example

#### Trace Permission Inheritance

[image]
[image]

Joslyn has the **Allow** permission inherited from her membership in the **Contributors** group, which has the **Allow** permission explicitly set on the repositories container node (all repositories) like so:

[image: allow via group]

#### Explicit Deny trumps explicit Allow

If I add another group that Joslyn is a member of and deny that permission on that group, then the permission is denied.

[image: joslyn's other group]

---

[image: new group permissions]

---

[image: new inherited permissions]

Even explicitly allowing the permission to Joslyn results in a denial of permission.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Josh, you're a lifesaver.  It's too bad the information is there but finding it is next to impossible.  I can't tell which permission related to the Complete button until you point it out.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. My problem solved.

Comment: "Make sure that you are not part of any groups that have privilege Denied"
This helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, simply abandon the pull request then reactivate the pull request.